# How can IronPython access a public static property defined in C#?

Tags: c#, static, import, ironpython, public

Consider this C# code:

```
public static class Graphics {
  public static Color white = new Color(255, 255, 255);
}
```

I can compile and import this from IronPython:

```
>>> import clr
>>> clr.AddReference("Graphics")
>>> import Graphics
>>> Graphics.white
<Color 255,255,255>
```

But I can't:

```
>>> import clr
>>> clr.AddReference("Graphics")
>>> from Graphics import *
>>> white
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dblank/Calico/src/engine.py", line 159, in execute
    source.Execute(self.manager.scope)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
<type 'exceptions.NameError'>: name 'white' is not defined
```

Is there something I can do to make white accessible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mark the field as readonly then we'll allow importing it via import * because it'll get added to Graphics.**all**.

Comment: Yes, that did it. Is there a way to make public static properties visible? public static int MyValue { get {} set {} }; doesn't seem to appear.

Comment: Oh, and what is .all? Can we add things to that in C#?